# How to retrieve array inside an array into a table using vue js

Tags: html, arrays, vue.js

i want to retrieve some array inside an array but i dont know how, please read my explanation first

here is my json response

```
{
"Value": [
    {
        "id": "5ff97d740e788778dd66ee25",
        "id_order": "ORD-434183",
        "nama_pelanggan": "Herman",
        "total": 80000.0,
        "jumlah_item": 4.0,
        "cart": [
            {
                "id_cart": "CART-112010",
                "nama_produk": "Ayam Bakar",
                "jumlah": 4.0,
                "harga": 20000.0,
                "subtotal": 80000.0,
                "notes": "ga ada"
            }
        ],
        "admin_no": "ADM-431525",
        "admin_name": "Admin",
        "created_at": "2021-01-09 16:55:00",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-09 16:55:00"
    }
],
"Status": true,
"Messages": [
    {
        "Type": 200,
        "Title": "TotalRows",
        "Message": "1"
    }
]}
```

as you can see the value of "value" is an array and in that array also have an array "cart"

i want to retrieve this array "cart" and put it in a table

here is how i retrieve the response using vue js [Mapping an Array to Elements with v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)

```
var vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    list: {
        items: [],
    },
}

            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('filterparams', JSON.stringify(filters));
            formData.append('display', JSON.stringify(_self.list.config.display));
            formData.append('auth', sessionStorage.getItem("token"));

            _self.$http.post(hostapi + 'order/GetByParamsHistory', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            });
            var obj = response.data;
            _self.list.items = obj.Value; // the value from array "Value"
```

here is the table html code

[image]

and now I don't know how to insert an existing array in the array into the html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the array on the basis of the array index.

Suppose, if `list` contains the json response's value field then you can access it like.
`list['0'].cart`.

Comment: thanks to you i can retrieve the array, but the contents of the cart array do not match the contents, like only taking from the first array, can you help me to solve this ?

Comment: all of my data order now have the same cart item in the front end, what should i do to solve this ???

Comment: With v-for we should also pass a key something like this: `<tr v-for="(row, index) in list['0'].cart" :key="index>`.

Comment: what is index ?

Comment: do you know how to implement increment in this code  `list['0'].cart` ?

Comment: Index is the unique attribute for each item to track the node, it can be any unique value.
Can you provide some more information that how many cart arrays you are passing?

Comment: thank you for your support, 1 data only have 1 array cart, and i have many data that have different value of array

Comment: i think the only way is to increment the index, but i dont know how

Comment: Can you share data that has a different value of array, as I am unable to understand your point.

Comment: do you have media social account ? would you like to help me please ?

Comment: here is the json response `https://pastebin.com/wset27Wy` The first scenario is that there will be a table containing all the data array "Value" which contains the order objects.

Then when clicking on one of the data a new table will appear containing the data from the existing cart array